# Using divs as a grid?

Tags: jquery, html, css, grid

Okay so I have been trying to get a div system to work as a grid and also margins to work with that as well. I need the last div in the grid to NOT have a margin. As you can see in my jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/kyFBr/, the last div has a margin to the right.

I can't simply use a different class for the last div that says "Picture four" because eventually this data will be pulled out of a database and I need the formatting to when that div changes position and another one appears in its place.

For the grid squares, I can only use the class "grid1".

The div that all the grid squares are contained in use this as the css:

```
div.events {
    width: 970px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
    text-align: left;   
}
```

And the grid's css is:

```
div.grid1 {
width: 219.5px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    float: left;
    padding:10px;
    background-image: url('debut_dark.png'); /*Image From SubtlePatterns.com*/
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

Anyone have a solution? Thanks.

Comment: Anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: did you tried with nth-child ?

Comment: why would you pick 970 as your frame? 960 is extremeley common in grid systems for a reason...... it divides up well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing is a result of CSS's inability to count until the more recent CSS level 3 properties.  The one you need is :nth-child and specifically `:nth-child(4n)` (the `n` represents every 4th and not just the 4th)

```
div.grid1:nth-child(4n) {
    margin-right:0px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tvx7m/2/show
Source: http://jsfiddle.net/tvx7m/2

This solution, of course, only works on modern browsers that support CSS level 3.

Real credit goes to @Frederik (make an answer and I'll delete mine)

Comment: If you look _super_ closely it still sticks out like 1 pixel on the edge, but not on [this](http://jsfiddle.net/yentup/kyFBr/5/show/)

Comment: If you add more divs though, this solution won't work. I'm not sure if there will _be_ more divs but it is worth consideration. http://jsfiddle.net/tvx7m/1/

Comment: @yentup thanks for pointing it out, but that's because of the OPS poor selection of grid sizes and not the method.  (also if you look super close, yours is shifted right by a pixel)

Comment: @Beno oops!!! forgot one thing for my selector.  I'll edit.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Joseph Marikle haha yeah, and using .5 is not very good for grids lol

Comment: Its still 1px off on the right side of the grid squares though :/

Comment: Fixed, well i just added added this: div.grid1:nth-child(4n) {
    margin-right:0px;
    width: 221px;
}

Answer (score 4):

So simple

http://jsfiddle.net/kyFBr/8/

a .row needs to have 960px, - 6px for the margins = 954 for the .wrapper
Than with some simple math:

```
.row{
    width: 960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align: left;     
}

.wrapper{
    color: white;
    width: 954px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 3px 3px 3px;
    background-image: url('http://subtlepatterns.subtlepatterns.netdna-cdn.com/patterns/debut_dark.png'); /*Image From SubtlePatterns.com*/
}

.wrapper p{ padding:15px; } /* DON'T USE PADDING ON THE GRID!! but here! inner elements! */

div.grid1 {
    width: 234px; /* MATH + */
    margin: 3px;  /* MATH = 960 */
    float: left;
    background-image: url('http://subtlepatterns.subtlepatterns.netdna-cdn.com/patterns/debut_dark.png'); /*Image From SubtlePatterns.com*/
}

div.grid1 p {  
    text-align: center;
    padding:15px;
}
```

If you want to go on with the math than do like:

```
.grid1, .grid2{
    position:relative;
    display:inline;
    margin:3px;
    float:left;
    background-image: url('http://subtlepatterns.subtlepatterns.netdna-cdn.com/patterns/debut_dark.png'); /*Image From SubtlePatterns.com*/
}

.grid1 {width: 234px;}
.grid2 {width: 474px;}
```

**[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/kyFBr/10/)**

Comment: This! this is the most correct and the most compatible solution.  This is how the good grid systems like the twitter bootstrap's version do it.  This needs more upvotes. +1

Comment: Thanks @JosephMarikle , I've built recently more than 5 versions of Grid layouts so I'm in good shape :)

Comment: Definitely more versatile for older browsers but +1 for you also @JosephMarikle. I think yours is a cleaner solution.

Comment: +1 re: padding, you can use [`box-sizing: border-box`](http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) to avoid having to wrap content in an extra element.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `.wrapper`'s width to: `width: 917px;`
And the `.grid1`'s `margin-right` to:

```
margin-right: 1px;
margin-left: 2px;
```

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/yentup/kyFBr/5/show/

It lines up *perfectly!*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create class like `.last` or `.omega` that you can add in addition to the grid class (an element can have multiple classes), resetting the margin-right to 0. Or use CSS3 `:last-child` pseudo selector.

For last-child probably you want to group your rows into... rows. otherwise you can use the nth-child to affect every third element

Or try creating the CSS with this nifty grid generator http://grids.heroku.com/

Comment: I thought :last-child too, but now that I look at the demo closer, I think the OP wants *every* fourth child to not have this margin.